# How important is Yatra in TIrthayatra

Tags: scripture, ganga, tirtha

This week Supreme Court of India and government of India didn't permit kanwariyas to bring "Ganga jal" from Haridwar. Instead they asked state governments to develop mechanism to make the water available through tankers in designated locations. For those unaware kanwariyas bring back Ganga jal to sanctity temples, murtis etc in their communities

In the past we have had helipads developed in Vaishnodevi Mandir making it easy for devotees to get darshana.

Now I know to uphold dharma the king/state needs to encourage or facilitate Yatras.

But how do we know where to draw the line so that essence of tirtha yatra is maintained ? After all Hinduism is not just reading scriptures but also rituals, penance etc.

Please provide answers from scriptures or traditional commentators.

Comment: Asking questions about politics is not a question about Hinduism and opinionated. See forum rules.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - It is not politics. And hardly opinionated. If you can't figure that out from question body then I can't help it

Comment: Furthermore I think it is a bit ridiculous to even think a site which is "about Hinduism" is suppose to ignore current events that are relevant to Hinduism.